# Proving a function is onto

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and one-to-one, and $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|g(x)|=\infty$. Is $g$ onto?

Comment: Suppose it were not. Can you find a contradiction to the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous injection which is not surjective. Then there is a $z\in\Bbb R$ such that $g(x)\ne z$ for each real $x$. As $g[\Bbb R]$ is connected, we have $g[\Bbb R]\subseteq(z,\infty)$ or
$g[\Bbb R]\subseteq(-\infty,z)$.

In the first case, since
$\lim_{|x|→∞}|g(x)|=∞$, we conclude that $\lim_{x→\pm∞}g(x)=∞$. Now, a continuous injection from the real line to itself is either strictly increasing or decreasing. As $\lim_{x→\pm∞}g(x)=∞$, if we take $M=g(0)$, then there had to be real numbers $r,s$ such that $g(x)>M$ whenever $x<\min\{r,0\}$ or $x>\max\{s,0\}$. But this cannot be if $g$ is decreasing or increasing. So we have a contradiction.

The case $g[\Bbb R]\subseteq(-\infty,z)$ is similar.